# Is there a way to export a filtered form to Excel in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Continuous form within a Navigation Form in access. I have set the form to allow "data entry" in the property sheet settings under the Data tab. With this setting the form loads to a new data entry record. The problem is with the "Allow to Data entry" set to yes, when I try export to Excel, it always exports a sheet with empty cells, it only shows the fields for the search criteria but no data.

I set the "Allow data entry to no" and when I did that the export to Excel button worked and exported data to an Excel sheet.

ExportWithFormatting
Object Type: Form
OutputFormat: Excel Workbook xlsx
OUtputFile: Blank
Auto Start: Yes
Template File:
Encoding: OUtput
Quality: Print

I would like for the export to Excel button to export data to Excel based on the search criteria I have in my form.

Comment: You can use VBA to combine the form's `RecordSource` and `Filter` properties, turn it into the new `RecordSource`, requery your form, export it, then restore the original `RecordSource` and `Filter`. There is probably an easier way, especially if you are willing to forego the formatting and export just data.

Comment: A simple report will export nicely.

Comment: @June7 it has to be able to export to an excel sheet....

Comment: @SunKnight0, I am a novice when it comes to vba, how would i go about that?

Comment: A report can export to Excel with VBA OutputTo method or right click menu or ribbon ExternalData/Export wizard. A simple report can look as nice as a table or query export. Complex reports using grouping and/or subreports don't do so well.

Answer (score 1):

It not clear why you using data enter = yes, as that means the form will ONLY  show new records you are entering. So, that idea is likely a bad idea.

However, assuming the form displays what you want after filtering?

Then something like this should work.

Place a button on the form (say up in the heading).

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()

  Dim strSQL     As String

  strSQL = Me.RecordSource

  strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & Me.Filter

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryExport")
     .SQL = strSQL
  End With

  ' now export the query  with critera to excel

  Dim strOutFile    As String

  strOutFile = "c:\ExcelData\Test.xlsx"

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "qryExport", strOutFile, True
end Sub
```

The query used in above is assumed to be a query on the table, and can be quite much any legal sql query - since our code OVERWRITES the query and sql each time, and then we export that query.

Comment: Hi the reason I left it to yes, is so that when the continuous form of 1000+ records opens, nothing it pulled up, up until a search criteria has been input, then you call the records needed

Comment: Ok, at least you have a reason for your choice (and that is a good answer). If you never use this form or data entry? If the form is only for selecting records? You  could use the openform with a where clause of id = 0.  Anyway, this issue seems to be fine for you anyway. And the above  Anyway, the above should create a working sql statement that is exportable to Excel.